# GridViewColumn autosize only work once

Tags: c#, wpf

I am storing column widths on application exit and restore them on startup. Everything works fine unless user double click header. This would cause column width become `double.NaN` which I understood is a *flag* for autosizing. Then I have problems.

While investigating the issue I noticed what setting column width to `NaN` will enable auto-resizing but **only for one time**.

Here is a repro:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="A" Width="NaN" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Then add two buttons with following click handlers:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => listView.Items.Add("abcd");
void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => listView.Items.Add("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
```

Clicking `button1` first will autosize column to fit `"abcd"`. Clicking then `button2` won't.

[image]

Why? Is there a workaround to have it either always autosizing or to at least disable user double-click resizing (tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686128/1997232) without success)?

Comment: Does `Width="Auto"` instead of `NaN` not work?

Comment: This prevents the user from being able to resize the columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181956/prevent-user-from-resizing-columns-with-wpf-listview

Comment: @TyCobb, `GridLength.Auto` is for `Grid`'s [`ColumnDefinition.Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width(v=vs.110).aspx). Here `GridViewColumn.Width` is of `double` type.

Comment: @mm8, I don't want to prevent user from resizing ;) Only from that *very special* (`double.NaN` lol) double-click auto-resizing.

Comment: @Sinatr Got it. I was looking at this question where the answer had the widths set as auto which I thought could fit your *have it ether always autosizing* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560581/how-to-autosize-and-right-align-gridviewcolumn-data-in-wpf

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307289/wpf-gridviewcolumn-width-auto-only-works-for-items-in-the-current-scroll-scope/6308331 when just the initial width is not properly computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the `Width` of the column on each update:

```
void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.Items.Add("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
    GridView gv = listView.View as GridView;
    gv.Columns[0].Width = gv.Columns[0].ActualWidth;
    gv.Columns[0].Width = double.NaN;

}
```

And to disable double-click resizing you could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `GridViewColumnHeader` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn Header="A" Width="Auto" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

```
private void listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) =>
    e.Handled = e.ClickCount == 2;
```

Comment: Seems to work. That's a dirty trick (setting value to current actual width and then again to `NaN`), I'd never thought to do so. Disabling also works, two answers in one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a [well know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931423/6996876) behaviour of the WPF `GridView`.

A generic solution for multiple columns is to register an event handler (my personal suggestion is for `SizeChanged`)

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" SizeChanged="listView_SizeChanged">
```

to do the update

```
private void listView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewColumn c in ((GridView)listView.View).Columns)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(c.Width))
        {
            c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
        }
        c.Width = double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Comment: typical absurd downvote: this is how at SO they guarantee the quality of answers :-)